# Dependencies on vcruntime140.dll and api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll

Tags: dll, windows-7

Windows 10 64-bit, VS2019 16.11.9

I have a C++ (native only) project which builds and executes on my development system, but on other Windows 10 systems, requires DLLs `libiomp5md.dll` and `vcruntime140.dll` to run. On other Windows 7 systems, it fails to run because `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll` is missing.

How can I determine specifically which function calls in my project are causing the requirements for `vcruntime140.dll` and `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll`?

I understand that `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll` is not a file, but a kind of link that Windows uses to locate the actual DLLs required, so I need to find a way to supply or point to these DLLs to allow execution on Windows 7.

Here is the output from `dumpbin /dependents`:

```
File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

Image has the following dependencies:

UxTheme.dll
libiomp5md.dll
api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll
KERNEL32.dll
USER32.dll
GDI32.dll
WINSPOOL.DRV
ADVAPI32.dll
SHELL32.dll
COMCTL32.dll
SHLWAPI.dll
ole32.dll
OLEAUT32.dll
oledlg.dll
gdiplus.dll
OLEACC.dll
IMM32.dll
WINMM.dll
VERSION.dll
imagehlp.dll
MSIMG32.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft ended extended support for Windows 7. And some dlls don't work with it.

This substitution for api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll may help:
https://github.com/nalexandru/api-ms-win-core-path-HACK

It's tested with Blender.